# Request for new user account via email Django

Tags: python, django, forms, email

I am trying to make a little function for a user to request an account and the information he puts in is sent to a person who will make an account.
I was following this example mostly http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/261/ but it is very old and might be inaccurate for I have got and thus I have problems with it.

I have this code currently:

#### account/models.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError

# A simple contact form with four fields.
class NewAccountForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

#### account/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from account.models import NewAccountForm
from django import forms
from django.core.mail import send_mail, BadHeaderError

def request_account_view(request):
        first_name = request.POST.get('first_name', '')
        last_name = request.POST.get('last_name', '')
        email = request.POST.get('email', '')
        message = (first_name + ' ' + last_name + '  has requested a new account for the email ' + email)
        if first_name and last_name and email:
                try:
                    send_mail('Request for Account', message, email, ['example@example.com'])
                except BadHeaderError:
                        return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thankyou/')
        else:
            return render_to_response('new_account.html', {'form': NewAccountForm()})

        return render_to_response('new_account.html', {'form': NewAccountForm()},
            RequestContext(request))

def thankyou(request):
        return render_to_response('thankyou.html')
```

#### urls.py

```
(r'^thankyou/$', 'account.views.thankyou'),
(r'^new_account/$', 'account.views.request_account_view'),
```

#### templates/new_account.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<form action="/new_account/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
    <label id="id_first_name">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="" id="first_name" />
    <label id="id_last_name">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" value="" id="last_name" />
    <label id="id_email">Email:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit Request"/>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting an error for:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

which occurs after I input name and password and click submit.
My email host is working fine because I previously was working on a "Forgot Password"
function.
I would really appreciate help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`RequestContext(request)` needs to be [used](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it). In your code below the second return will never be hit so you are not passing RequestContext to the template.

```
    else:
        return render_to_response('new_account.html', {'form': NewAccountForm()})

    return render_to_response('new_account.html', {'form': NewAccountForm()},
        RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: could you suggest a way to fix it please?

Comment: try just getting rid of else: return render_to_response('new_account.html', {'form': NewAccountForm()}), that way the second will return RequestContext, see if thats works

Answer (score 0):

Did you add `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` to your list of middleware classes, MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES? (It should come before any view middleware that assume that CSRF attacks have been dealt with.)

You can learn more about Django's CSRF protection here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/